# Почему gulp сборка не работает не могу выполнить npm i?

Tags: gulp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему гальп сборка не работает не могу выполнить npm i ?

Comment: `npm i -g windows-build-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Ну написано же - питона нет. Поставь питон 2.7 и пропиши его в path.

Comment: питон 2.7 а зачем питон нужен? сидел на четвертой версии gulp  все работало ,но проект достался на 3.9 не могу запустить

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти, скорее всего питон нужен чтобы собрать солюшен плюсов (ну или просто си), который потом будет собираться соответствующим компилятором.

Comment: как его поставить ведь для гальп обычно надо npm и gulp i  и все,тут больше вопрос из-за чего его нету питона ,что не установилось или что помешало?

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти, питон ставится обыкновенно [с сайта питона](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Но вообще, я уже более точный ответ дал.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n4uvna фото

Comment: установил https://prnt.sc/n4uvna

Comment: все равно ругается https://prnt.sc/n4v0im

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти, питон 2.7, а не 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

А вообще, ошибка происходит при установке модуля node-sass. Если пормотать лог наверх, то будет ссылка, по которой он не смог скачать бинарник. Убедись, что соответствующая ссылка доступна на компе, где ты выполняешь установку модулей. Возможно она заблокирована файрволлом, либо надо обновить версию пакета из-за того, что старый бинарник удалили.

Если возможности скачать бинарник нет, то надо установить питон и компилятор с/си++, к которому могут потребоваться дополнительные библиотеки. В общем, там мутная схема дальше будет - лучше не связываться с ней.